# How can i convert days names to dates of the current month?

Tags: php, date, time, type-conversion, dayofweek

I have an array of days in a month excluding friday and sunday as they aren't inculded in policy, i want to convert the array of days names to the dates of the current month but when i convert it is in incorrect format because it shows for different month [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTQ3u.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of all the dates you want the following way:

```
//create a array of DateTimes of the days in the month
$allDateTime = iterator_to_array(new DatePeriod(new DateTime(date('Y-m') . '-1'), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTime(date('Y-m-t'))));
//filter out the Fridays and Sundays
$filteredDateTimes = array_filter($allDateTime, function ($date) {
    $day = $date->format("N");
    return $day !== '7' && $day !== '5'; //7 for sunday, 5 for friday
});
//format the to dd-mm-yyyy
$filteredDates = array_map(function ($date) {
    return $date->format("d-m-Y"); //you can choose the format you prefer here 
}, $filteredDateTimes);
print_r($filteredDates);
```

You can run this snippet here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8459152d9020d767110ad2732997af10d2e0d275